# Create HIVE Table with fixedrecord length

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

How to create hive table with fixed record length for specific column?

My data is:

```
ROW1~|`900~|`3103~|`2015~|`AA~|`1002003829

ROW2~|`900~|`3103~|`2015~|`BB~|`1002005103

ROW3~|`900~|`3103~|`2015~|`CC~|`1002003829

ROW4~|`900~|`3103~|`2015~|`DD~|`1002003829

ROW5~|`900~|`3103~|`2015~|`FF~|`1002003829
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a `ROW FORMAT SERDE` option and using `RegexSerDe`

For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE event (
  code STRING,
  location STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "input.regex" = "([^]{4}) ([^]*)"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Specifies `code` field of fixed length `4`.

References:

[Relevant LanguageManual DDL section](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RowFormat,StorageFormat,andSerDe)

[GettingStarted example of ROW FORMAT SERDE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-ApacheWeblogData)

[Example of using SerDe for fixed length columns](http://www.confusedcoders.com/bigdata/hive/use-hive-serde-for-fixed-length-index-based-strings)

Answer (score 0):

1) All fields must be string.

2) In this case all the fields have the fixed size of 10 chars and there is no field separator.

3) output.format.string, in case of write, will output the record in the same format they have been read.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test(field1 STRING, field2 STRING, field3 STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
     "input.regex" = "(.{10})(.{10})(.{10})", 
     "output.format.string" = "%1$s%2$s%3$s"
     )
LOCATION '/path/to/table';
```